# What is the best possible way to change Bootstrap version in SXA?

Tags: sxa

Is there any easy way or what is a good way to change the Bootstrap version in SXA. I have used the **4.6.1** for my frontend design, but I know **SXA** uses the **4.3.1** version. The way I did it is that I made a **Base Theme** called **Bootstrap 4.6** with all of the **styles** and **scripts** folders and files and I injected that base theme to my site theme. Everything works fine but now I have issue where in **console** it now shows multiple tags of a certain tag. To be more precise here is the picture of what I am trying to say.

[image]

Is this something related to me adding the new base theme or?

#### Here is another example:

[image]

#### Many more!

[image]

So is this normal or it is not? I think personally that this issue started to happen when I added this new base theme to my site theme. Beacuse as you can see there are different **optimized-min** files for everything

Answer (score 1):

Probably because two Bootstrap themes are loaded now (if you haven't removed previous one).

Take a look on grid definition item
`/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Bootstrap 4/Bootstrap 4 Grid Definition`

it has a link to theme specified in `Grid Theme` field (this is the place where all assets live)

You could replace reference to your theme **(it's not recommended to modify SXA items)** but I would prefer to create custom bootstrap definition (copy of bootstrap 4 with reference to your theme).

Once you create your custom grid definition (literally just a copy of existing one with modified theme) remember you have to change it for your site (**Settings** item
`/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings`, field: `Grid Mapping`) so logic will take your new grid together with new theme.

That's the way you should configure it.

By default grid theme is injected via code here:
`Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.Pipelines.AssetService.AddGridTheme, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid` (there is no reference in base themes field on a theme - thanks to that you can use single theme with multiple grids)